# This could be the nickname for a nuclear family of females?

Tags: society, language, alternate-reality, social-norms

In omegaverse we can have a nuclear family formed by an Alfa Female and a Beta or Omega Female whose kids will be all females.

I get the inspiration to call this kind of family **"Doll house"**, but lather I remembered that gender roles are different in Omegaverse. *Dolls are not related to all kind of females.*

But I don't know if the better is get another way to refer this kind of family, stick with "Doll house" or give up this nickname thing.

*The nickname (or slur) is not that nescessary.*

Comment: Welcome to the site, Aramati. Is Omegaverse an existing universe, or one you're working on? I've never heard of it. Also, what, exactly, is your question? It seems you're asking the community if you should use a nickname and what that nickname should be. In that case, this is likely to be put on hold as _too-opinion-based_ until clarification is provided in the form of an [edit].

Comment: How about "coven"?

Comment: My VTC reason was "unclear what you're asking", because I have no idea what omegaverse is, and how two females can have biological children (definition of nuclear family, as I understand). But I agree that even if these would be known, it probably would be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Omegaverse is a fanbase where humans are discriminated between 3 Etho, namely: Alphas, Betas and Omegas.
All Alphas are reprodutives like males, Omegas are reprodutives like females and Betas are like the real word. (Actually there's much more details, but there are the important ones now)

I'm creating my own Omegaverse and am sincerely surprised that there's no a Omegaverse tag in a comunity like this one.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast seens a bit forme agressive than I expected, but may work.

The intention was really something than can be used both insult and no-offensive definition.

Comment: Thanks @Frostfyre, I'll rewrite the question if this is the better.

Comment: [Omegaverse](https://fanlore.org/wiki/Alpha/Beta/Omega).  Note that this is a class of fiction, not a specific set of rules.  We might very well need the rules to be more explicitly stated.  For example, is a given person always the same group?  So once an alpha, always an alpha?  I'm not sure that the current answer realizes that.  I'd suggest cat house, but that's already associated with whorehouse in colloquial English.  Perhaps kitty den.  That would go well with something like rooster coop for an all male house.  All miss/mister?  Jills/Jacks?

Comment: OMG @Brythan, these options are awesome. You are absolut right, each ABO universe has its own rules, I don't realized if they are relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect the women themselves would just call it a "family", so the nickname would come from others as a way to deride or differentiate from whatever is the norm or average. Nicknames often originate in an insult, but the actual slur would depend on who does the branding.

If couples with a male alpha are the norm, the insult might reference the female alpha being a "false" alpha.

If female couples who are equal partners are the norm, the insult might reference heterosexual pretensions.

"Doll House" says to me that the insult originated in a male-dominated environment, and that a female-only couple is a pretend or immature relationship. It doesn't differentiate between alpha/beta roles, it just references the lack of men.

I don't see other women creating this term as little girls usually don't play with only female dolls, on the contrary dolls getting married is very common in our universe (contrary to TV commercials I don't see little girls pretend their Barbie™ is going to the mall with her girlfriends to shop in consumerist paradise, rather role-play mimics domestic relationships, parenthood, dating and marriage), so women might not see dolls as a purely girl-only experience even if men do. (Men of my generation actually collect more dolls, but they call them action figures.)

Of course over time the insult/nickname might be taken up by the group itself as language evolves. It's somewhat counter-intuitive to remember that "gay" was an insult meaning frivolous and unserious in a time when people were expected to conform to "serious" adulthood – it makes little sense as an insult in today's society where childhood is extended well into middle age. I don't know how appealing "doll house" would be for the female alpha, but she might use it if it was in the common language. You could even "lampshade" it by having one of the alpha women say she doesn't like the term. Discussing the ulterior meaning of words is a very feminist thing that happens in our universe, so if you are worried about offending people you can have a character say what is wrong with it (it's called "hanging a lampshade on it").

There's not enough info about your Omegaverse for me to say whether your nickname works or not, but hopefully this helps to put perspective on it?